# What is difference between MainActivity.this and this

Tags: android

When I type code like this in **MainActivity**:-

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Some text...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

It shows the error

> There is no applicable method to
> '(com.example.MainActivity.(anonymous),java.lang.String,int)'

but

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Some text...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This not shows the error,
So is any difference present in `MainActivity.this` and `this`

Answer (score 4):

When you are doing this :

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Some text...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

you are creating an **anonymous class** with the implementation of interface `OnClickListener`.

Now, when you use `this` keywork inside `onClick()`, the `this` here refers to the instance of the anonymous class created (although you also have access to the instance of MainActivity), therefore, to refer to the instance of MainActivity, you have to use `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: In kotlin, you can use `this@MainActivity`